# running functions synchronously in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to call a function to get a value from a 'subproduct' table and insert it in to another table. However the value which I am returning is not fetching the latest value from table and it is getting returned even before the snapshot part of the function is getting executed. I want it to run synchronously. Is there a better way in which it can be written.

```js
function getGSTvalues(para1) {
  var gstVar = 1;
  var gstVarPromise = SubProductRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      if (para1 == child.val().subproductName) {
        gstvar = child.val().gst;
        console.log("InsidePromise" + gstVar);
      }
    });
    console.log("outside fun : " + gstVar);
  });
  console.log("outside fun1 : " + gstVar);
  return gstVar;
};
```

This is where I am calling the above function:

```js
var gstans = getGSTvalues($('#edit_ProductSubType').val());
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using synchronous logic would be a big step backwards. The best solution here would be to use the asynchronous pattern correctly and provide a callback function to `getGSTvalues()` which is executed after the async operation completes and receives the result as an argument. Try this:

```
function getGSTvalues(para1, cb) {
  var gstVar = 1;
  var gstVarPromise = SubProductRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      if (para1 == child.val().subproductName) {
        gstVar = child.val().gst;
      }
    });

    cb && cb(gstVar);
  });
};

getGSTvalues($('#edit_ProductSubType').val(), function(gst) {
  console.log(gst);
  // work with the value here...
});
```

Another alternative would be to return the promise from `SubProductRef` from `getGSTvalues()` and apply `then()` on that in the calling scope, although this would render the function largely redundant.

Also note that JS is case sensitive so `gstVar` is not the same as `gstvar`. I corrected this above.